# how to make the shadows in Cycles stronger from the grid table lamp

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

Hope someone could help me. I have modelled table lamp the mesh is totally a grid i need to make render result with strong dropped shadow from the light point inside the mesh, the problem the in the 3d viewport with Eevee engine i can see shadow but render result the shadow is too soft in both Cycles and Eevee.
Thanks in advance!
I add screenshot and render result here also blender file.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using emission light inside the globe on the filament part,
I add screenshot and render result. [image]
[image]